# Retreiving all contacts from GMail via oAuth - Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token

Tags: import, oauth, gmail

Ok, I'm so close but I can't quite get this to work.  I am successfully connecting to Google's Oauth system and I get back these url params:

```
endpoint    https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken
key     greatdentalwebsites.com
oauth_token     4/SBJ3hchIUl-2Sz40s2q9NcQ7kL77
secret  cEdJDfn31Z3LC_Aw4gQZ4tnL
token   4/SBJ3hchIUl-2Sz40s2q9NcQ7kL77
token_secret    LMXzzHty4yWwAZPD8g14Xsqn
```

So I take that and try to construct my url request:

http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/jeff.gladnick@gmail.com/base?alt=json&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=1595725&oauth_timestamp=1310612128&oauth_consumer_key=greatdentalwebsites.com&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_token=4%2FSBJ3hchIUl-2Sz40s2q9NcQ7kL77&oauth_signature=DxtHUcEsPXYiqmRUj8l%2BAYvfmcQ%3D

Which google rejects:
HTTP/1.1 401 Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token. Connection: close Expires: Thu, 14 Jul 2011 02:55:38 GMT Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2011 02:55:38 GMT Server: GSE X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Now what the hell - I'm using oAuth not Authsub?  Any ideas?

Comment: Authsub is just a name, don't have to worry that it's not OAuth... One possible issue is that you haven't requested the right scope in the beginning (when getting request token) and later the token that you use to access a particular resource is not allowed to access that resource

Comment: This was the scope I requested:
'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom'   Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, change the scope to: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/

And that is now giving me some different feedback during the reg process, displaying contacts instead of gmail - which seems good.  But I still get the same error:

HTTP/1.1 401 Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token. Connection: close Expires: Thu, 14 Jul 2011 16:53:56 GMT Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2011 16:53:56 GMT Server: GSE X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Comment: Sorry, I can only shoot in the dark, but I cannot tell you what can be the issue with that... generally HTTP 401 means UNAUTHORIZED request and if you are doing the signing correctly and you have a valid token, then maybe something with the scopes can be a problem. Are you sure that your signature is right? I guess it is, because it should give a different error... BTW, I haven't used google APIs with OAuth and I can't think of what can be the reason for this error

Comment: Wouldn't a signing error produce a error code of:

signature_invalid base_string:

Comment: Have you added a Google Account to the "Google APIs Console" page here: https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect#project:<youridhere>:access

be sure to add your project id in that URL before clicking.

You apparently have to add a google account or it won't work.